# DICOM C-StoreSCP: How to know in advance number of images SCU will send?

Tags: dicom

I have DICOM C-StoreSCP application which receives DICOM images from my other C-StoreSCU application. My SCU always send one (and only one) and complete (all images from given study) study on one association. So SCP always know that all images received from SCU belong to single study. I know I can also check StudyIUID; but that is not my point of interest here.

I want to know total number of images in study that is being transferred. Using this data, I want to display status like "Received 3 of 10 images..." on screen. I can count images received (3 in this case) but how can I know total number of images in given study (10 in this case) that is being transferred?

**Workaround:**

On receiving first C-Store request on SCP, I should read the StudyIUID and establish new association with SCU (SCU should also support Q\R SCP capabilities in this case) for Q\R and get total count of images in study using C-Find.

Limitations: -

- SCU should also support Q\R SCP features.
- SCU should compulsorily send image count in C-Find response.
- SCU should always send all images from only one study on one asociation.

I can easily overcome the limitations if I write SCU (with Q\R SCP capabilities) myself. But my SCP also receive images from third party SCUs those may not implement features necessary.

Please suggest if there is any DICOM compatible solution?

Is this possible using MPPS? I have not worked on MPPS part of DICOM yet.

**Conclusion: -**

Accepted answer (kritzel_sw) suggests very good solution (using MPPS) with only one drawback. MPPS is not mandatory service for each SCU. MPPS is applicable to only SCUs those actually acquire the image i.e. modalities. Even not all modalities support MPPS out of the box; they need unlock of feature with additional license cost and configurations. Also, there are lot of scenarios where modalities push instances to some intermediate workstation and the workstation further push it to SCP.

**May be, I need to look into combination of DICOM + NON_DICOM wayout.**

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38279743/5779732

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question, but no simple answer.

Expecting a Storage SCU to support the C-FIND-SCP as well is not going to work well in practice unless you are referring to archive servers / VNAs.

MPPS is not a bad idea. All attributes (Study, Series, SOP Instance UID) you need are mandatory, so it *should* be valid to rely on them. "Should" because I have seen vendors violating these constraints. 
However, how can you be sure that the SCU has received the complete study? Maybe the study consists of CT and MR series, but the SCU sending the images to you only conforms to CT and rejects to receive MRs.

You might want to consider the Instance Availability Notification service which is another service class with which information about "who has got which image" can be made available to other systems. Actually this would exactly do what you need, because you know in advance for each AET ("device") which images are available there. But this service is not widely supported in practice.

Even if you really know which images are available on the system that is sending the study to you - how can you be sure that there is no user sitting in front of it who has just selected a sub-set of the study for sending.

Sorry, that I cannot provide a "real solution" to you but for the reasons I have mentioned above, I am not aware of any real-world system which supports the functionality (progress bar) you are describing.

Comment: Even though you do not provide "real solution", your answer answer discusses multiple possibilities and their pit-falls. This helps me a lot. Thanks a lot.

Comment: My SCP is actually a part of PACS-Server. SCU may be any SCU (modality/workstation etc). About the purpose, my PACS displays list of studies received. If SCU is sending the study, it will be immediately displayed in work list with number of images received and count will be refreshed after certain interval. Now, with "images received" counter, I also want to display "total count". So the output will be something like "Received 3 of 10 images...". Here, I can easily count number of instances received so far but how should I know total number of instances for study that is being transferred.

Comment: In this case IAN is not the way to go as it is usually not supported by modalities. So the workflow for MPPS would be to build a database from the MPPS messages (IHE requires the image manager to receive these messages, so you can expect the RIS to be capable of forwarding them to your archive) yielding a list which SOP Instances belong to which study. This can be used as a reference when images are transferred. Make sure to support modalities that do not support MPPS as well, i.e. do not deny to access a study for which you have more images than indicated by MPPS

Comment: Great; MPPS really makes sense; but one doubt. In my (very little) knowledge about MPPS, only SeriesIUID is sent back to RIS in NCreate request. SOPIUIDs are not sent through MPPS. Am I wrong?

Comment: Have a look at PS3.4, Table F.7.2.1.1 (MPPS Subset Spec). In the section "Image Acquisition Results" you will find that there are Series Instance UIDs as well as SOPClass and -InstanceUIDs _may_ be included. As for many other attributes, they are not mandatory.

Comment: Addition: The MPPS messages I have seen in practice (not too many unfortunately) _did_ contain the references to the images without exception

Comment: @kritzel_sw   Are you available for consult work.  I am implementing MPPS and need a little help to get started.

Comment: @SScotti: I am a professional DICOM consultant :-D. You can obtain my services through the company that I am working for. Not sure if this is the answer you wanted to have...